# How to manage the tab opened manually

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

If selenium opens new tabs via code like this `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("some url");` there is no problem to switch between: `driver.SwitchTo().Window(gmailDriver.WindowHandles.Last());` but how to switch on tab I opened manually? What is the difference between tab opened by selenium code and tab opened manually?

Comment: You'll still use getWindowHandle to get current handle and getWindowHandles to get all handles.  (The one that isn't current is the new tab's handle...)  However I think Firefox (maybe other browsers, too?) will have a different local handle for a fresh tab.... once navigated to a remote URL, it'll change to a remote handle.  (They have two different handles set for local context or remote... the local would also apply to a file on your system or possibly localhost)

Comment: which languge binding are you using

Comment: getting window handles does NOT have a deterministic order.